# Python - Delete files matching with multiple ‘or’

Tags: python

I am trying to use below to remove some files has names matched the criteria, contains either ‘aa1’, ’bb1’, ’cc1’, ’dd1’.

It doesn't give any error however there is not a single such file to removed.

```
for f in os.listdir(working_folder):
    if 'aa1' in f or \
       'bb1' in f or \
       'cc1' in f or \
       'dd1' in f:
        try:
            os.remove(os.path.join(working_folder, f))
        except OSError:
            print "there's no such a file"
```

Question 1: what’s the way to improve the multiple ‘or’ in the code?

Question 2: how can I have it to print **“there’s no aa1”, “there’s no bb1” etc etc..**?

I tried below and it neither working:

```
for f in os.listdir(working_folder):
    for k in pattern:
        if re.search(k, f):
            try:
                os.remove(os.path.join(working_folder, f))
            except OSError:
                print "there's no such a file"
```

---

A way suggested by squiguy:

```
working_folder = 'C:\\'

pattern = ['aa1', 'bb1', 'cc1', 'dd1']

files_to_delete = []

for a in pattern:
    for f in os.listdir(working_folder):
        if a in f:
            files_to_delete.append(f)

for b in files_to_delete:
    os.remove(os.path.join(working_folder, b))
    print os.path.join(working_folder, b) + " removed"
```

Comment: in the 2nd part, you iterate through every element in the pattern list, but then you do "re.search(pattern, f)", which is trying to match the filename to a list. it should be "re.search(k, f)"

Comment: thanks, xgord. I tried modified it accordingly but still no printing anything...

Comment: in your code, it will only print if you try to remove a file that doesn't exist. you'll need to add other print statements if you want to see what's happening

Comment: thanks again, xgord. none of the files exists but it doesn't tell. how can i improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `any` to shorten that conditional.

```
patterns = ['aa1', 'bb1', 'cc1', 'dd1']

for f in os.listdir(working_folder):
    if any(pattern in f for pattern in patterns):
        try:
            os.remove(os.path.join(working_folder, f))
        except OSError:
            print "there's no such a file"
```

Comment: @MarkK Well do you know if these files actually exist? You're going to have to print out some more information somewhere to see what is happening. Right now it only prints if you have an error trying to remove it.

Comment: thanks again, squiguy. there ain't any such files at all, and I want the code tell me. How can I do that?

Comment: @MarkK Why not filter them beforehand? Find all files matching a pattern, delete them, and print the missing patterns. Break up your problem into parts and go from there.